Does there exist an example of meaningful information about an automated individual decision-making algorithm?
The GDPR Article 14 includes provisions for the data subject to have meaningful information about an automated individual decision-making algorithm that which produces legal effects concerning him or her or similarly significantly affects him or her.  A judgement in December confirms this includes credit reference agencies if a decision by a third party mostly uses that to make such a decision.
Has anyone ever produced and published such meaningful information such that one could point at that as an example of what to do?  I would really be interested in such a description of a complex modern statistical/machine learning/big data type of algorithm.  One that had been accepted as such by a court would be the best I guess, one advocated by privacy advocates and/or statisticians would be a close second.

This is currently being worked on mostly through articles 57 and 97 of the AI Act (regulatory sandboxes and advisory committees for delegated acts). For more traditional cases there are some guidelines from the EDPB... https://www.edpb.europa.eu/our-work-tools/our-documents/guidelines/automated-decision-making-and-profiling_en
